# Colors in git output?

Tags: git, colors

I have seen some examples on people getting colors in git output. I tried the following guide http://scie.nti.st/2007/5/2/colors-in-git but unfortunately it didn't succeeded.

Is there anything else that needs to be done to get colored output? I'm using .oh-my-zsh together with regular Ubuntu and color works in the term.

**Edit**: I'm looking for colors like from this example (while doing a clone): http://calip.so/quickstart-install-calipso.html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try this.

```
git config --global --add color.ui true
```

Or you can create a simple ~/.gitconfig to start with.
something like.

```
[gui]
    recentrepo = /Users/name/Workspace/repo/src/stable
[user]
    name = name
    email = name@domain.com
[apply]
    whitespace = nowarn
[core]
    editor = vim
[color]
    diff = auto
    status = auto
    branch = auto
```

Comment: Thanks. As I wrote, I have tried this, but still no color. Well, no color is not exactly true. I get colored +'s and -'s while doing fast-forward. I'm looking for more colors like in the link I now posted.

Comment: So this too does not work for you? That's strange. Which version, platform you are on.

Comment: lol totally misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3):

The example you posted is not supposed to be coloured; it is only because the blogging engine used by http://calip.so/ mistreats preformated text as code blocks, and highlights tokens as if it were program source.

For example, `//github.com/cliftonc/calipso.git` is coloured differently because `//` marks the start of a *comment* in many programming languages, and `in`/`var`/`done`/`using` are reserved *keywords*.